# Error: No value provided for option '--port' Ruby on Rails & PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am studying a project which is build on Ruby on Rails, I am newbie... I run a ruby-on-rails web application on Ubuntu. It connects to PostgreSql. When I run start_server.sh file, receive below **error**:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb:228:in `parse_peek': No value provided for option '--port' (Thor::MalformattedArgumentError)
```

start_server.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# AWS environment variables
export AWS_S3_BUCKET="testing.mytest.resources"
export AWS_REGION="ap-southeast-2"

# Host and Port
rails s -b $LOCAL_DB_HOST -p $LOCAL_DB_PORT
```

Can you please tell a solution for this error?

Comment: Most likely your environment variables are not set.

Comment: What do you get when you run `echo $LOCAL_DB_HOST` and echo $LOCAL_DB_PORT  in your terminal ? If they are empty then you need to set them

Comment: It returns empty when I run echo $LOCAL_DB_HOST and echo $LOCAL_DB_PORT

Comment: Could you please tell me where to put these global environment variables?